# SFML static linking problem: sfml-system-2.dll not found

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, sfml, static-linking

### Quick Summary

I have a very simple SFML application that I'm trying to **cross-compile to Windows, from Linux**. I am trying to **statically link the SFML libraries** with the application.

However, when I run the compiled application in a Windows 10 Virtual Machine, I get DLL import errors: *"The code execution cannot proceed because *.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this issue."*

Some of the .dll files that were missing are: sfml-system-2.dll, sfml-window-2.dll etc.

### Source Code

Here is the program I am trying to statically link:

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(void) {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Hello World!");
    sf::CircleShape circle(600.f / 2.f, 60);

    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    break;
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(circle);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### How I compiled

```sh
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ ./main.cpp -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

The compilation succeeds, and outputs a file: "a.exe"

As you can see, I'm using Mingw32, and I'm passing the `-static` parameter, which usually works on my other C++ programs, but it seems like SFML isn't successfully being statically linked.

### My Environment

I'm thinking I might have the wrong environment for cross compiling SFML?
I downloaded SFML 2.5.1 *(GCC 7.3.0 MinGW (SEH) - 64-bit)* from [sfml-dev.org](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/), placed the shared-object files into /usr/x86_64-w64-ming32/lib/, and then placed the include files into /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/.

### What I tried

I tried taking the Windows SFML binaries (sfml-system-2.dll, sfml-window-2.dll, etc.) and placing them in the same directory as the application. They were successfully found & imported **but** then, I got an execution error: *"The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)."*. No idea what that means, but I assume it can be fixed by statically linking SFML.

I apologize if this is a nooby question, or if I'm doing something obviously wrong! I'm quite inexperienced with cross-compilation. Cheers!

Comment: Do SFML even *have* static libraries to link with?

Comment: As for the 0xc000007b error, I suggest you read e.g. https://www.diskgenius.com/how-to/fix-error-code-0xc000007b.php (found very easily when searching for *0xc000007b windows error*).

Comment: Your problem is here: "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b).". No idea what that means -- so find it out, it's pretty easy! Also, there's a tool called dependencywalker that I'd highly recommend. That said, you should extract a [mcve], e.g. whether SFML is relevant at all is still at question. Lastly, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah I just checked, they do. For example, "libsfml-system-s.a" is included with the SFML download. the '-s' is to indicate "static".

Comment: I don't see anything about it in [the link options documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) but the libraries themselves are sensitive to ordering, perhaps it's the same with the `-static` flag? What happens if you place it before the libraries?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried placing the `-static` flag before the library linking. It didn't seem to change anything, unfortunately. I also had the idea to pass `-DSFML_STATIC` because I remember having to define that on Windows, but it also made no difference.

Comment: you should link static libraries (postfix `-s`) if you want to statically link the libraries :) either build sfml on your own using `-DSFML_STATIC` or use the static libraries provided by the package you downloaded.

Comment: I have the same problem. I can compile perfectly fine, however when I run the `exe` on another computer, it shows the same errors...